# What are the default fonts on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome

I installed Gnome 3 and it changed a lot of settings. I decided it wasn't for me and uninstalled it but the fonts are still different.

If you have are using default settings on 14.04, a screenshot of this gnome-tweak-tool window would be much appreciated!

[image: gnome-tweak-tool/fonts]

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go. Re-installed 14.04 just the other day.

[image: Ubuntu 14.04 Default Fonts]